# Failed to get contentProvider

Tags: android

i just new to Android and learn it by book. Please help me to find mistakes that may had in my small practice program. I could successfully created database but i couldn't use my query function to browse results from SQLite database due to an exception which says "Failed to find provider info for com.latrobe.database".

```
Exception:06-10 01:13:55.510 25546-25546/com.latrobe.database E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.latrobe.database
06-10 01:13:55.962 25546-25655/com.latrobe.database E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f2949cda5c0
06-10 01:14:00.401 25546-25546/com.latrobe.database E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.latrobe.database
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.latrobe.database">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name=".DatabaseProvider"
            android:authorities="com.latrobe.database.DatabaseProvider"
            android:exported="true">
        </provider>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
package com.latrobe.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by hexinhao on 16/5/30.
 */
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String CREATE_BOOK = "create table book ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "author text, "
            + "price real, "
            + "pages integer, "
            + "name text)";
    public static final String CREATE_CATEGORY = "create table Category (" + "id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "category_name text, "
            + "category_code integer)";

    private Context mContext;

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK);
        db.execSQL( CREATE_CATEGORY);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Create succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists Book");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists Category");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.latrobe.database;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final int BOOK_DIR = 0;
    public static final int BOOK_ITEM = 1;
    public static final int CATEGORY_DIR = 2;
    public static final int CATEGORY_ITEM = 3;
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.latrobe.database";
    private static UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "book", BOOK_DIR);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "book/#", BOOK_ITEM);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "category", CATEGORY_DIR);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "category/#", CATEGORY_ITEM);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getContext(),"BookStore.db",null,2);
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case BOOK_DIR:
                cursor = db.query("Book",null, null, null, null, null, null);
                break;
            case BOOK_ITEM:
                String bookId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                cursor = db.query("Book",null,"id=?",new String[]{bookId},null,null,null);
                break;
            case CATEGORY_DIR:
                cursor = db.query("Category",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
                break;
            case CATEGORY_ITEM:
                String categoryId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                cursor = db.query("Category",null,"id=?",new String[]{categoryId},null,null,null);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }


        return cursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case BOOK_DIR:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.latrobe.database.book";
            case BOOK_ITEM:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.latrobe.database.book";
            case CATEGORY_DIR:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.latrobe.database.Category";
            case CATEGORY_ITEM:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.latrobe.database.Category";
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Uri uriReturn = null;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case BOOK_DIR:
                break;
            case BOOK_ITEM:
                long newBookId = db.insert("Book",null,values);
                uriReturn = Uri.parse("Content://"+AUTHORITY+"/book/"+newBookId);
                break;
            case CATEGORY_DIR:
                break;
            case CATEGORY_ITEM:
                long newCategoryId = db.insert("Category",null,values);
                uriReturn = Uri.parse("Content://"+AUTHORITY+"/category/"+newCategoryId);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }




        return uriReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
// 删除数据
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int deletedRows = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case BOOK_DIR:
                deletedRows = db.delete("Book", selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case BOOK_ITEM:
                String bookId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                deletedRows = db.delete("Book", "id = ?", new String[] { bookId }); break;
            case CATEGORY_DIR:
                deletedRows = db.delete("Category", selection, selectionArgs); break;
            case CATEGORY_ITEM:
                String categoryId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                deletedRows = db.delete("Category", "id = ?", new String[]
                        { categoryId });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return deletedRows;
    }




    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int updatedRows = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case BOOK_DIR:
                updatedRows = db.update("Book",values,null,null);
                break;
            case BOOK_ITEM:
                String bookId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                updatedRows=db.update("Book",values,"id=?",new String[]{bookId});
                break;
            case CATEGORY_DIR:
                updatedRows = db.update("Category",values,null,null);
                break;
            case CATEGORY_ITEM:
                String categoryId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                updatedRows=db.update("Category",values,"id=?",new String[]{categoryId});
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }



        return updatedRows;
    }


}
```

---

```
package com.latrobe.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this, "BookStore.db", null, 2);
        Button createDatabase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_database);
        createDatabase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
        });
        Button addData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_data);
        addData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("name", "The Da Vinci Code");
                values.put("author", "Dan Brown");
                values.put("pages", 454);
                values.put("price", 16.96);
                db.insert("Book", null, values);
                values.clear();
                values.put("name", "The Lost Symbol");
                values.put("author", "Dan Brown");
                values.put("pages", 510);
                values.put("price", 19.95);
                db.insert("Book", null, values);
            }
        });
        Button updateData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_data);
        updateData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("price", 10.99);
                db.update("Book", values, "name = ?",
                        new String[] { "The Da Vinci Code" });
            }
        });
        Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_data);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete("Book", "pages > ?", new String[] { "500" });
            }
        });
        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.query_data);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.latrobe.database/book");
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                        null, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("name"));
                        String author = cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("author"));
                        int pages = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("pages"));
                        double price = cursor.getDouble(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("price"));
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "book name is " + name);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "book author is " + author);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "book pages is " + pages);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "book price is " + price);
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        });
        Button replaceData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replace_data);
        replaceData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    db.delete("Book", null, null);
                    // if (true) {
                    // throw new NullPointerException();
                    // }
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("name", "Game of Thrones");
                    values.put("author", "George Martin");
                    values.put("pages", 720);
                    values.put("price", 20.85);
                    db.insert("Book", null, values);
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authorities in the manifest and the provider don't match.

Also your Activity seems to access the database directly instead of talking to the provider. Is this the correct code?

Comment: Yes,I forgot to paste the code of another program which demand content provider to access other application's database.But now,I sovled the problem, i was not clearly understand the meaning of the name and the authority in the provider but i just modified it to the right one so it now would able to use contentProvider in its own program but also accessible by other program as well. Thanks for your reply.